# Meaning of locus of a line

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, applications

I am studying analytical geometry where i encountered the below problem.I searched the concept on the MSE site but found that question on the topic are poorly framed.

We are given the equations of the following three lines in general form.
$$L_1:u_1=0,v_1=0$$
$$L_2:u_2=0,v_2=0$$
$$L_3:u_3=0,v_3=0$$
We need to find the locus of a straight line intersecting these lines .In my understanding , a locus is the path traced by a point subject to some conditions . I have never heard of locus of something called the straight line.Therefore ,I have following questions :-

1. Can someone interpret what is the intuitive / physical meaning of locus of a straight line . Does it mean in this example ,all the lines that intersect the given three lines form some kind of surface in 3-D space ? Can we extend this definition therefore to locus of a circle , locus of an ellipse , locus of hyperbola etc.
2. If the above question can be solved using the definition ?

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful this is, but I've always considered the locus of a line to be the collection of all points that are collinear with two given points.

Comment: I think that doesnot help because the question is related to variable straight line varying with some parameters in space.

Comment: If you have three lines that don't intersect in 3d, the surface should be a hyperboloid of one sheet. The three lines are then of one ruling, and the lines of the other ruling are the lines you seek. See Hilbert Cohn-Vossen.

Comment: Perhaps the question is to find the "locus of *all* straight lines intersecting these lines", not "a" straight line? A "locus" is indeed a collection of points. The "locus" of a straight line would be just that straight line. However, the locus of all straight lines intersecting all three of $L_1, L_2, L_3$ would be the collection of points on any of those lines. However, beyond that there is no help, because your definition of $L_1, L_2, L_3$ is worthless. What are $u_1, u_2, u_3, v_1, v_2, v_3$? What do they represent? How do they identify the points on the lines?

Comment: @PaulSinclair$u_1, u_2, u_3, v_1, v_2, v_3$ are the six planes , first two of which represent the first line , next two represent the second line and the last two represent the third line.

Comment: If they are "planes", then what does it mean to claim that they are $0$? Is $0$ a plane in your universe? How do two *planes* "represent" a *line*?

Comment: $a_1x+b_1y+c_1z+d_1 = 0 ,a_2x+b_2y+c_2z+d_2 = 0 $ are two planes , taken together , represent a line which is common to both planes  (considering planes are not parallel.)