# The locus of a line in 3D passing intersecting two other lines

Tags: 3d, coordinate-systems, locus

A line through any point on the curve $x^2-y^2=1 , z=0$ intersects two lines $y=x, z=1$ and $y=-x, z=-1$. Required is the locus of the line . Just to clarify(as I have seen people question), the above form of a line represents the two planes that intersect to form the line.

Here I couldn't understand what does the problem mean by the locus of a line . I have seen this [Meaning of locus of a line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3964080/meaning-of-locus-of-a-line) but it is inconclusive. It would be very helpful if someone could explain the reasons behind the solution of this question. Thankyou.

Comment: BTW, this locus is called a [ruled surface](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=ruled+surface)

Comment: Yes thanks for that info! I put up the wiki link here for other references https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruled_surface&ved=2ahUKEwjok6Ti77b3AhVQ4HMBHQjYAa4QmhN6BAgTEAI&usg=AOvVaw0ZJo8S4cJ1nkHyJV-YgUFx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a point on the first line,

$P_1 = (t, t, 1) $

And a point on the second line

$P_2 = (s, -s, -1) $

Find the line that joins $P_1$ and $P_2$ ,

$P(t) = (1 - r) P_1 + r P_2 = ( (1 - r) t + r s , (1 - r) t - s r , (1 - r) -r ) $

Set $z = 0 $, then

$1 - 2 r = 0$, so $ r = \dfrac{1}{2} $

So the intersection point is

$P(t,s,r) = ( \dfrac{1}{2} (t + s) , \dfrac{1}{2} (t - s) , 0 )$

Now we want $x^2 - y^2 = 1$ , hence

$ (t + s)^2 - (t - s)^2 = 4 $  or $  t s = 1 $

Substituting this,

$P(t, r) = ((1 - r) t + r /  t, ( 1- r) t - r /  t, 1 - 2 r ) $

which is the line

$ P(t, r) = (t ,t , 1) + r ( - t + \dfrac{1}{ t} , - t -\dfrac{ 1}{t} , -2 ) $

This is the locus of all lines satisfying the given conditions.

Comment: Okay, I'll correct that.

Comment: [3D interactive plot](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyNUstugzAQvPsrVvQQO-DETlupqsQ_5B6llcWjWAVsFjdV-_Vdk7fSQxAI7Xhm9uUaXQc2VBica0ewnXcYoGiM7dnOIJ9hFmaCeQ85eIOmqwLa4t23LjyWjDWW8CdWkkkOPGQgG5tBYwVbR4HnG8Lo1dsMiJRB4VqHefJQK5VEUnpiyfjd8JSqiXcmjgMGrtPwthKTsbo1ri-N5Z0C1rria6Sad1URHPIN1xLFPEAKuCTZMZT7UMvVHLfnPJM6myagl4cRUIiUjxBx0Y9RSQbOm8KGn1wtXv71mKYoo9PdLtQAVa9hSalZOcR10HIktE4Q9sxqhzCA7fe75SOa_qPisnVTNlkO9C8HynE4iQeNTSNOsHhlQI8PcURToTzkdIS5IskVoMVE3XflbE_3hJOOjO1vlWt10UUd78CJ3Nq-OnKvKWy9GBv3zUNTdVWelAY_E_EH2-jCOw==&lang=sage)

Comment: @GrabaCoffee,It indeed makes sense to me now. By the way  that 3D plot is brilliant, It shows  the circle well. Just a follow through, the hyperbola seen in the plot (on rotating it), how can we tell it's plane from here? I would think it corresponds to the $ts=1$ part as seen in the answer.It seems like the perpendicular plane, so I will try to work it out analytically